# Is the set of $n,m$ s.t. $2^n-3^m=1$ or $3^m-2^n=1$ finite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is the set of $n,m$ s.t. $2^n-3^m=1$ or $3^m-2^n=1$ finite?
tried factoring but got nowhere, not sure what theorem or subject applies to this question.

PS : no it is not a homework, but if a book has this as homework please give a reference.

Tagging as possible elementary-number-theory , modify if incorrect

Comment: Look at the first equation mod $8$.  Look at the second equation mod $8$, find a condition on $m$, add $2^n-1$ to both sides, factorize the left.

Comment: @BobJones : what is the significance of $\mod 8$ ? why not $\mod 7$ or $\mod 16$ for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not just finite, it is a singleton. There is a much stronger property:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture